# Android and tabactivity

Tags: android, tabs

I have the following example:

When I click on Tab2 the activity doesn't fit between the begining of the android screen and till to the Tabs line. Why? what can I do to try and fit the screen?

```
Main.java

public class Tabs_androidActivity extends ActivityGroup {
    public TabHost mTabHost;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    tabHost.setup(this.getLocalActivityManager());


    TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
    spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec1.setIndicator("Tab 1");

    TabSpec spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
    spec2.setIndicator("Tab 2");
    spec2.setContent(new Intent(this, Tab2.class));



    TabSpec spec3=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 3");
    spec3.setIndicator("Tab 3");
    spec3.setContent(R.id.tab3);



    tabHost.addTab(spec1);
    tabHost.addTab(spec2);
    tabHost.addTab(spec3);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    }
```

}

```
Tab2.java
public class Tab2 extends  Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 

    TextView call;
@Override 

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    setContentView(R.layout.logs);
  ///....


}
}
```

and main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
         >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >


            </LinearLayout>


        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```

logs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/call"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: do you want to fit an `Activity` to full screen ?

Comment: I want the activity to fit the screen till it hits the tab menu. currently the new activity is on the full screen and my tab menu cannot be seen clearly because when cliicking on tab2 the tab menu gets also written

Answer (score 0):

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
         >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"/>
       <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Your Tab Activity:

```
public class TabActivity extends android.app.TabActivity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab_layout);
//  Resources res=getResources();
    TabHost tabHost=getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;

    intent=new Intent().setClass(this, Tab1Activity.class);
    spec=tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator(yourimageID).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent=new Intent().setClass(this, Tab2Activity.class);
    spec=tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator(yourimageID).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent=new Intent().setClass(this, Tab3Activity.class);
    spec=tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator(yourimageID).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```